# Decision tree model with R, recall and precision

Tags: decision-tree, precision-recall

I made a decision tree model. 
I obtained recall and precision for my model. However, I need to obtain recall and precision for each node.

How can I do that with R?

My code:

```
tree1<- rpart(Interested ~ . , data= training_set, method = 'class', control =rpart.control(minsplit =16, minbucket =16 , cp=0))

rpart.plot(tree1, extra = 4) # pic 1.2 
printcp(tree1)
plotcp(tree1) #min error : 0.000219 
ptree1 <- prune(tree1, cp=0.000219) 
rpart.plot(ptree1, extra = 4, uniform=TRUE) #--trining 
pred=predict(tree1, training_set, type='class') 
table(pred = pred, true=training_set$Interested)
```

Comment: please include the code of what you've done so far

Comment: tree1<- rpart(Interested ~ . , data=  training_set, method = 'class',
              control =rpart.control(minsplit =16, minbucket =16 , cp=0))
rpart.plot(tree1, extra = 4)  # pic 1.2
printcp(tree1)
plotcp(tree1)    #min error :  0.000219
ptree1 <- prune(tree1, cp=0.000219)
rpart.plot(ptree1, extra = 4, uniform=TRUE) 

#--trining
pred=predict(tree1, training_set, type='class')
table(pred = pred, true=training_set$Interested)

Comment: please review the update on your post and confirm that is your code